# Query with Django doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. This is my first post here!:

I have been trying to "print" on some website I made with Django some objects from a database that I made with HeidySQL.

The app inside Django is called users. So 127.0.0.1: 8000/users, inside this I have another page in 127.0.0.1:8000/users/login that is loading fine.

I successfully synced this DB with Django, I even managed to see some rows in the Django shell, which is why I concluded everything seems to be connected well.

This login.html file atm has this:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ allcharacters_query }} </h1>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

The issue is that it doesn't display the names of my characters_list.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.models import Characters
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index (request):
    return render(request,'users/home.html')

def return_charnames (request):
    allcharacters_query = Characters.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'users/login.html',{"allcharacters_query": 
    allcharacters_query})
```

And this my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, patterns
from .import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$',login,{'template_name': 'users/login.html' })

]
```

I don't really know how to fix this. I have read lots of documentation from the official Django site and watched lots of videos, however, I am stuck here.
Thanks all!

Comment: What is `characters_list `. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Well, that is unfinished, so id ignore the loop part, I just wanna display for now the <h1>{{ allcharacters_query }} </h1> part.

Comment: Wait, where is the url patten to render `return_charnames` ?. You're using django's login view for `/login/`

Comment: I don't know.. what you mean, sorry

Comment: @Aranu Espin , Shouldn't the url pattern for login look like `url(r'^login/$',views.return_charnames)` ?

Comment: Omg yea, it works now, jeez I was stuck here for almost 2 days. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem . :) Glad I could be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use your view render not django's views for login if you're overriding login methods.

```
 url(r'^login/$',views.return_charnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
{% for lista in characters_list %}
```

by:

```
{% for lista in allcharacters_query %}
```

`characters_list` doesn't exist in your template.

And there is no URL calling your view `return_charnames` in your url file.

Comment: Hello, I just did it, still doesn't work. Atm Id suggest to ignore the loop part and just show the <h1>{{ allcharacters_query }} </h1> part

Comment: The problem comes from your URL, login just calls your index view and not `return_charnames`

Answer (score 0):

You should add return_charnames to urls.py to display html content in proper url.